# Can I plug my Arduino into my USB port and have power applied to it via add on shield board?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, shield

I'm building a digital soldering station using Arduino nano. I need to add code to the sketch for troubleshooting.  I's like to add "Serial.print" statements but don't know if it's possible to run both USB power and power supply connects at the same time.

Comment: Show us the schematic you want to test out. I did not exactly understand how you want to connect the USB port and/or where the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Nano has a series diode on the USB VBUS specifically for this use case, so that you can safely power the Arduino Nano from a separate 5V power supply but still connect the USB.